# Issues with server-side prepared statements in MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.2.2

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

**Background**

I got a report from a customer who complained that they got the following error message in their log files after performing some updates on their server:

`ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.1.49]Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)`

**My findings**

Google gave me the following [interesting result](http://iammysql.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/cant-create-more-than-max_prepared_stmt_count-statements/).

After reading the above blog post I started to experiment, and sure enough - when updating to the new ODBC driver (5.2.2, aka "MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver") all statements are now server-side prepared by default. (also see the announcement [here](http://lists.mysql.com/announce/803)).

Here's two lines from the global log using 5.2.2:

```
[192.168.0.150]|134302|0|Prepare|INSERT INTO `a1gt6` (`TimeStamp`, `Temperature`) VALUES (?, ? )
[192.168.0.150]|134302|0|Execute|INSERT INTO `a1gt6` (`TimeStamp`, `Temperature`) VALUES ('2012-11-25 12:40:27', '7.03750000000000000e+001' )
```

**The problem**

I wouldn't have a big issue with my statements being turned into prepared statements if it wasn't for the fact that they apparently are not closed by the server (in a timely manner, see update below), as indicated by the above error message and the result from the command `show global status like "com_stmt%";`

```
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    1
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    1
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
```

The above table shows the result after running a statement a single time using Connector/ODBC 5.2.2. Below is the output from `show global status like "com_stmt%";` using Connector/ODBC/5.1.11

```
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
```

Below is the C# test method I've been using to determine the cause of the problem.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestOldfashion()
{
    int option = 16 + /*FLAG_MULTI_STATEMENTS*/ 67108864;
    string odbcString = @"DRIVER={{{0}}};SERVER={1};UID={2};PWD={3};OPTION=" + option + ";CharSet=utf8;";
    using( System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection con = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection( string.Format( odbcString, new object[] { "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver", "server", "user", "password" } ) ) ) {
        con.Open();
        con.ChangeDatabase( "fooDB" );
        using( System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() ) {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable ( foo, value ) VALUES ( ?, ? );";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "foo", 2 );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "value", "asf" );
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the CREATE statement for the table:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

**Pre-posting update**

Just before posing this, I executed the `show global status like "com_stmt%";` again and now it gives the following result, so it appears that the server *does* clean up the statements, but much too late (considering the above error message). The last one remains unclosed( in `Com_stmt_reset`) even after 30 minutes.

```
Com_stmt_close  6
Com_stmt_execute    7
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    7
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  1
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
```

The [announcement](http://lists.mysql.com/announce/803) mentions that it is possible to disable the server-side prepare by adding the `no_ssps=1` option to the connection string. This seems to work (only briefly tested it) but it does not feel like a solid solution. I'd rather use the defaults as much as possible as I expect the MySQL devs knows what the best practices are. Likely I'm doing something wrong or not understanding things properly.

**The questions**

If the server now turns my regular statement into a prepared statement (as opposed to the old client-side emulation), why doesn't it clean it up in a timely manner so that the above error is avoided?

I'd expect the statement to be closed/released when the end of the using-scope for the OdbcCommand is reached, but that is apparently incorrect?

I'd much appreciate if someone could shed some light on this. Unfortunately it is 00:55 so I can't stay up to answer/clarify things now, but will check in tomorrow morning again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67340) to which a patch has been submitted and approved.  You can:

- wait for a fixed release;
- apply the patch yourself and recompile;
- downgrade to 5.1; or
- use `no_ssps=1`.

Comment: Oh, wow. One could wish they could have written something on the download page, since this bug is rather severe (even though the bug is classified as non-critical)